# How to get a scrollbar in a div with fixed header and footer?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I have an website and some problems with the scrollbar.

What I want I can best explain with this image.

[image: My Website]

But I can't get the scrollbar like this.

I have tried some, here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA9k3/)

In this fiddle I also have:

```
div[role="main"]
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 60px 0;
}
```

But this margin is not OK, how do I know what margin I need without knowing the header and footer height.

Comment: you can get this layout using javascript/jquery easily without knowint the height of header and footer. javascript automatically calculate for height of div role=main for you on every resolution. Have you tried that?

Comment: @HappySingh from where you are?

Comment: This have to be possible by html/css. I've seen it before but can't find it back.

Comment: @jack how will you calculate if monitor resolution is more than height of the content div at that time how will you calculate the height of div role-main. can you specify please using css.

Comment: I dont use css that does calculation, so simply sorry!

Comment: @HappySingh so done with this.. ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be slowed by using padding and box-sizing = border-box on body ( with body height 100% it will count padding into height, so the box with scroll will be exactly between header and footer)

```
html {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 padding: 60px 0px;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

div[role="main"] {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100%;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/wPucQ/

EDIT: Added forgotten HTML tag in code

Comment: Just check the scroll bar is going behind the footer which is not the exact solution.

Comment: Did you looked at jsfiddle ? ( Or are you using mozilla 3.6 - / IE 7- )

Comment: In Google Chrome this seems to work. But in FireFox it isn't :(

Comment: I fixed it. Use `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;` for all browser compatibility THANKS!!

Comment: Would you please clarify your comment "Forget HTML tag in code"?  Does that mean "*Forgot* HTML tag in code"?  This works for me *with* the CSS on the `html`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the scrollable element a height so the scroll-bar position can be calculated.

```
div[role="main"]
{
    height:400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 60px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkxV4/

Comment: If you're using it to display an entire page it would be much easier (and more usable) to sticky the header/footer to the viewport.

Comment: you mean by sticky the fixed header and footer? Cuz thats what I did :)

Comment: Update using CSS `calc()` to handle varying screen sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/51ywzqaf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention Min-height or height for this div
div[role="main"]{ overflow-y: scroll; margin: 60px 0; min-height:400px;}

Comment: Mention height is kinda hard if I don't know the screen height of the user. Just some px is not the right way. % is another option, but the fonts are different px height in todays browsers/devices.

Answer (score -1):

See my fiddle for entire logic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA9k3/7/embedded/result/)
http://jsfiddle.net/MA9k3/7

Jquery code:

```
var doc_height = $(window).innerHeight();

var header_height = $("header").height();
var footer_height = $("footer").height();

var div_height = doc_height - (header_height + footer_height);

$("#content").css({
    "height": (div_height - footer_height) + "px",
    "margin-bottom": footer_height + "px"
});

alert($("#content").height());
```

Comment: I didn't mention javascript nor jQuery. It is possible in pure HTML CSS. I've seen it before. Anyway thanks for your help. All help is welcome :)

Comment: then you are looking for this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/2a7SB/1/ or  see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167160/conditional-sticky-css-footer-with-fixed-header

Comment: Where are the arrows of the scrollbar? This is what I want to prevent. Else I would give my html scroll and have the same result