# max-height: 100% div within complex layout

Tags: html, css

I have a weird CSS issue I cannot get my head around.
My page has a rather complex layout with fixed header and footer and a flexible content-area.

Now within this content area, I would like to create scrollable div, that by default uses the full height of the outer container, but not more.

Everything works fine with the scrollable div being the only element between header and footer.

[Working demo](http://www.hacksrus.net/files/demo.html)

Unfortunately however, as soon as I put the scrollable div inside a simple fixed-width container to center it on the page, the browser sizes it according to it's inner content, so that is not scrollable anymore, but the lower content disappears because of the outer div's *overflow: hidden*.

[Non-working demo](http://www.hacksrus.net/files/demo_with_container.html)

Any help is very much appreciated, I've literally spend the last days trying to figure this out.

Thank you,

Pascal

### Solution

As I am unfortunately not allowed to answer my own question, here is the solution that worked for me:

I was able to solve the problem by giving the `#container` a `height` of `100%`.
The result can be seen here: www.hacksrus.net/files/demo_working.html (I was not allowed to post another hyperlink either.. ;-))

I would very much appreciate if **someone could explain the reason** for this!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was not allowed to post these in the original question, so here are some screenshots for illustration:

[Working without container illustration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aUfkX.png) and
[Non-working with container illustration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gJgLx.png)

Comment: Why do you need both `#container` and `#scrollableContent`? Setting `overflow: auto;` on `#container` seems to do the job.

Comment: Looks like my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741871/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-in-a-div-with-fixed-header-and-footer) and [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/wPucQ/4/)

Comment: I specifically need the inner div `#scrollableContent` to be scrollable (or rather have the proper height at least) because I am going to build a custom scrollbar next to it. This could possibly be done using `overflow: auto` on the container and `position: fixed` on my custom scrollbar, but I would very much prefer to understand the problem with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

ok try this, after the div '**scrollableContent**', create a div and give its name '**centerAlign**' and add this code to your css file

ok, here is your code, which one i tested.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      * { 
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        font-size: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      header {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #c00;
      }

      #content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        bottom: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #c00;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #scrollableContent {
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #c00;
      }
      #centerAlign {
            width:745px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#999;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>header</header>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="scrollableContent">
        <div id='centerAlign'>
        <div>
          <p>BEGIN</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>Foo</p>
          <p>END</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay sorry, now I see what you did. The problem with this approach is, that I will have to create another non-scrollable element within `#container`. As pointed out above, this could probably be achieved using `position: fixed` on that element, but that would be a nasty solution. Thank you anyway, this is definitely my Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

In container class set the

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solves the issue in this particular case. For my needs however, I explicitly need the inner div to be sized properly (see comment above). If there is no way to achieve this, I will properly try to go with this solution, but I would like to understand the issue first.

Answer (score 0):

ok try this, after the div '**scrollableContent**', create a div and give its name '**centerAlign**' and add this code to your css file

```
#centerAlign {
    width:745px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this could possibly help? (Tried it and it didn't change anything)