# scrollbar not working properly in div with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am building a website and I am facing some problems with the scrollbar for divs. I have a fixed header and footer and the divs in between must stay between the header and footer. In case of overflow a scroll will appear.

**What I am Trying** is similar to [How to get a scrollbar in a div with fixed header and footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741871/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-in-a-div-with-fixed-header-and-footer)

But I cant make it work correctly.

### JS Fiddle of What I Am Trying

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPucQ/49/)

I could make it work by giving `body{height: 84%;}` but it will different in different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Now that jsfiddle is back...

Here is an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/wPucQ/54/)** for what you wanted

the following is the main change that was necessary:

```
div[role="main"]
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -70px 0 -30px;
    padding: 70px 0 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #4CD3BF;
}
```

---

Do something like this:

Not much content: **[CODEPEN1](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/Kfelq)**

Lots of content:  **[CODEPEN2](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/xcCLo)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

### CSS

/* Assuming header and footer height of 64px */

```
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0;
    padding: 64px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 64px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: what to do if the footer is different in "CODEPEN2"

Comment: Check out the updated fiddle - there, the header and footer have different heights

Comment: if you didnt notice the footer is not at the bottom pf the page

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but by me the footer IS at the bottom...i checked this on chrome and firefox...

Answer (score 0):

there are more than 1 answers to this problem. the easiest way to do this is to wrap the main content (so no header and footer) in a absolute positioned div. set the divs to to the bottom of the header and the bottom to the top of the footer eg

fiddle: http://jsbin.com/onipiq/2/edit

css :

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;

}
.contentContainer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note that this example will not scroll on most touch devices but will work fine on desktop.