# How to stop my scrollbar from pushing my header?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with my scrollbar that's overriding my header, is there some CSS property I can use to move the scrollbar "on-top" of my header? I have a transparent background which I thought would do the job.

Basically, how can I make my scrollbar hover above the header, instead of pushing it to the left?

[image]

As you see in the pic, the scrollbar is taking over the full width of the header.

Here is my scrollbar CSS:

```
'@global': {
  '*': {
    'scrollbar-width': 'thin',
  }
  ,
  '*::-webkit-scrollbar': {
    width: '1rem', height: '1rem',
  }
  ,
  '*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
    backgroundColor: '#d6dee1', borderRadius: '20px', border: "6px solid transparent", backgroundClip: 'content-box',
  }
  ,
  '*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#a8bbbf'
  }
  ,
  '*::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a margin-top for the webkit-scrollbar-track :

```
'*::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent';
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

This post explains it pretty good: [Change scrollbar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height)

EDIT:
This post has a very similar problem:
[How to get a scrollbar in a div with fixed header and footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741871/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-in-a-div-with-fixed-header-and-footer)

The problem there was solved by fixing the header.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I've been added the margin top, but the track is still there and pushing the header to the left?  The thumb is now not in the header space, but the track is still there. Any other ideas that come to mind?

Comment: I hava added a link I think that the solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!!